# Splitting multiple objects returns only one

Tags: powershell, split

I am attempting to pull multiple files from a directory and split the filenames, and rejoin them as the variable `$c1Output`, however when I echo the variable it is only listing one of the files.

```
$outputImages = GCI -Path $c1Output\*.jpg -R
$outputImages = $outputImages.Name
    $a, $b = $outputImages.Split(".")[0..1]
        $outputImages = $a + '.' + $b
```

If I echo the variant `$outputImages` at any point before the split it still lists the entire directory, but after the split the variable only provides one of the files.

Additionally the files I'm addressing are always named like `BARCODE.POSITION.PROCESSCLASS.jpg` so if anyone has a better way to select only `BARCODE.POSITION` please share that.

Comment: `$outputImages = $outputImages |ForEach-Object {$a,$b = $_.Split('.')[0..1]; "$a.$b"}`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen -  Please do not use comments to answer the question; propose your code as an answer, and include a brief explanation of what it's doing and why, and perhaps links to relevant references.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen thanks for the faster way of doing that but even with that command when i echo the variable it only shows one file.

Comment: How many objects does `$outputImages` contain after you've only ran your first `gci` command?

Comment: How many objects? It will vary, can you explain why that matters?

Comment: I've tested the code as a oneliner and it returns multiple strings:  `$outputImages = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\folder\jpgs -Include *.jpg -Recurse | ForEach-Object {$a,$b = $_.Name.Split('.')[0..1]; "$a.$b"}`

Comment: This is working for me @JamesC. Please submit as an answer and ill approve it. Why did you ask how many objects there were? I'm trying to learn why that matters with the `GCI` command. Thanks!

Comment: Was just checking you did have multiple files being passed in to start with, made that mistake before haha.

Comment: @JamesC. Oh yeah.. that makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script can be made into a one-liner with `Get-ChildItem` piped to `ForEach-Object` which splits `Name` property then assembles and outputs the first two items from the split.

```
$outputImages = Get-ChildItem -Path $c1Output -Include *.jpg -Recurse | ForEach-Object {$a,$b = $_.Name.Split('.')[0..1]; "$a.$b"}
```